# Why eclipse filling my texture with color?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opengl-es

I am making a game and one of my objects there is a white filling in its corners here: [image]

Can you help me to fix it I dont want to have any color in the corners just empty texture like the others objects? Btw they are from one texture file and there is no sense to fill only this with colors.
This is my loading class:

```
package com.vratsasoftware.zbhelpers;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Preferences;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;

public class AssetLoader {
    public static Texture texture, logoTexture, texture1;
    public static TextureRegion bg;
    public static TextureRegion grass;
    public static Animation logoAnimation;
    public static TextureRegion logo, logoDown, logoUp, playButtonUp,
            playButtonDown, ready, gameOver, highScore, scoreboard, star,
            gameLogo, noStar, retry, firstCandy, secondCandy, mmLogo;
    public static TextureRegion barTopUp, barTopDown, bar;
    public static TextureRegion androidLogo, appleLogo, enemyLogo;
    public static Sound dead, flap, coin, fall, shoot, hit;
    public static BitmapFont font, shadow, whiteFont;
    private static Preferences prefs;

    public static void load() {
        logoTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/logo.png"));
        logoTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
        mmLogo = new TextureRegion(logoTexture, 0, 0, 512, 114);

        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture.png"));
        texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest);

        texture1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture1.png"));
        texture1.setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest);


        playButtonUp = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 83, 29, 16);
        playButtonDown = new TextureRegion(texture, 29, 83, 29, 16);
        playButtonUp.flip(false, true);
        playButtonDown.flip(false, true);

        ready = new TextureRegion(texture, 59, 83, 34, 7);
        ready.flip(false, true);

        retry = new TextureRegion(texture, 59, 110, 33, 7);
        retry.flip(false, true);

        gameOver = new TextureRegion(texture, 59, 92, 46, 7);
        gameOver.flip(false, true);

        scoreboard = new TextureRegion(texture, 111, 83, 97, 37);
        scoreboard.flip(false, true);

        star = new TextureRegion(texture, 152, 70, 10, 10);
        noStar = new TextureRegion(texture, 165, 70, 10, 10);
        star.flip(false, true);
        noStar.flip(false, true);

        highScore = new TextureRegion(texture, 59, 101, 48, 7);
        highScore.flip(false, true);

        gameLogo = new TextureRegion(texture1, 67, 444, 160, 36);
        gameLogo.flip(false, true);

        bg = new TextureRegion(texture1, 0, 0, 490, 225);
        bg.flip(false, true);

        grass = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 43, 143, 11);
        grass.flip(false, true);

        logoDown = new TextureRegion(texture1, 0, 225, 340, 200);
        logoDown.flip(false, true);
        logo = new TextureRegion(texture1, 0, 225, 340, 200);
        logo.flip(false, true);
        logoUp = new TextureRegion(texture1, 0, 225, 340, 200);
        logoUp.flip(false, true);

        TextureRegion[] birds = { logoDown, logo, logoUp };
        logoAnimation = new Animation(0.06f, birds);
        logoAnimation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP_PINGPONG);


        //Pipe!!!
        barTopUp = new TextureRegion(texture, 192, 0, 24, 14);
        // Create by flipping existing skullUp
        barTopDown = new TextureRegion(barTopUp);
        barTopDown.flip(false, true);

        androidLogo = new TextureRegion(texture1, 0, 455, 60, 30);
        androidLogo.flip(false, true);
        appleLogo = new TextureRegion(texture1, 460, 245, 300, 230);
        appleLogo.flip(false, true);
        enemyLogo = new TextureRegion(texture1, 492, 0, 225, 225);
        enemyLogo.flip(true, true);

        bar = new TextureRegion(texture, 136, 16, 22, 3);
        bar.flip(false, true);

        dead = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/dead.wav"));
        flap = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/flap.wav"));
        coin = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/coin.wav"));
        fall = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/fall.wav"));
        shoot = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/shoot.wav"));
        hit = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/hit.wav"));

        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/text.fnt"));
        font.getData().setScale(.25f, -.25f);

        whiteFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/whitetext.fnt"));
        whiteFont.getData().setScale(.1f, -.1f);

        shadow = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/shadow.fnt"));
        shadow.getData().setScale(.25f, -.25f);
        // Create (or retrieve existing) preferences file
        prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("MMGame");

        if (!prefs.contains("highScore")) {
            prefs.putInteger("highScore", 0);
        }
    }

    public static void setHighScore(int val) {
        prefs.putInteger("highScore", val);
        prefs.flush();
    }

    public static int getHighScore() {
        return prefs.getInteger("highScore");
    }

    public static void dispose() {
        // We must dispose of the texture when we are finished.
        texture.dispose();
        texture1.dispose();
        // Dispose sounds
        dead.dispose();
        flap.dispose();
        coin.dispose();
        fall.dispose();
        shoot.dispose();
        hit.dispose();
        font.dispose();
        shadow.dispose();
    }
}
```

EnemyLogo is the planet with the problem.

And in this is my render class where I am using them:

```
package com.vratsasoftware.gameworld;

import java.util.List;

import aurelienribon.tweenengine.Tween;
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenEquations;
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenManager;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;
import com.vratsasoftware.gameobjects.BonusLogo;
import com.vratsasoftware.gameobjects.EnemyLogo;
import com.vratsasoftware.gameobjects.Grass;
import com.vratsasoftware.gameobjects.Logo;
import com.vratsasoftware.gameobjects.ScrollHandler;
import com.vratsasoftware.tweenaccessors.Value;
import com.vratsasoftware.tweenaccessors.ValueAccessor;
import com.vratsasoftware.ui.SimpleButton;
import com.vratsasoftware.zbhelpers.AssetLoader;
import com.vratsasoftware.zbhelpers.InputHandler;

public class GameRenderer {

    // Game Objects
    private Logo logo;

    // Game Assets
    private Animation logoAnimation;
    private TextureRegion bg, grass;
    private TextureRegion logoMid, mmGameLogo;
    private TextureRegion bonusLogoPlanet1, bonusLogoPlanet2, enemyLogo, bonusLogoRocket;
    private TextureRegion ready, gameOver, highScore, scoreboard, star, noStar, retry;

    private ScrollHandler scroller;
    private Grass frontGrass, backGrass;
    private BonusLogo bLogo1, bLogo2, bullet;

    private EnemyLogo enemyObject;

    private GameWorld myWorld;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;
    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

    private SpriteBatch batcher;

    public SpriteBatch getBatcher() {
        return batcher;
    }

    private int midPointY;

    // Tween stuff
    private TweenManager manager;
    private Value alpha = new Value();

    private Color transitionColor;

    // Buttons
    private List<SimpleButton> menuButtons;




    public GameRenderer(GameWorld world, int gameHeight, int midPointY) {
        myWorld = world;

        // The word "this" refers to this instance.
        // We are setting the instance variables' values to be that of the
        // parameters passed in from GameScreen.

        this.midPointY = midPointY;
        this.menuButtons = ((InputHandler) Gdx.input.getInputProcessor()).getMenuButtons();

        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(true, 136, gameHeight);

        batcher = new SpriteBatch();
        batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        // Call helper methods to initialize instance variables
        initGameObjects();
        initAssets();

        transitionColor = new Color();
        // setupTween
        prepareTransition(255, 255, 255, .5f);

    }

    private void initGameObjects() {
        logo = myWorld.getLogo();
        scroller = myWorld.getScroller();
        frontGrass = scroller.getFrontGrass();
        backGrass = scroller.getBackGrass();
        bLogo1 = scroller.getBonusLogo1();
        bLogo2 = scroller.getBonusLogo2();
        bullet = scroller.getBullet();
        enemyObject = scroller.getEnemyObject();
    }

    private void initAssets() {
        bg = AssetLoader.bg;
        mmGameLogo = AssetLoader.gameLogo;
        grass = AssetLoader.grass;
        logoAnimation = AssetLoader.logoAnimation;
        logoMid = AssetLoader.logo;
        bonusLogoRocket = AssetLoader.androidLogo;
        bonusLogoPlanet1 = AssetLoader.appleLogo;
        bonusLogoPlanet2 = AssetLoader.appleLogo;
        enemyLogo = AssetLoader.enemyLogo;
        highScore = AssetLoader.highScore;
        scoreboard = AssetLoader.scoreboard;
        retry = AssetLoader.retry;
        ready = AssetLoader.ready;
        star = AssetLoader.star;
        noStar = AssetLoader.noStar;
        gameOver = AssetLoader.gameOver;

    }

    private void drawGrass() {
        // Draw the grass
        batcher.draw(grass, frontGrass.getX(), frontGrass.getY(), frontGrass.getWidth(), frontGrass.getHeight());
        batcher.draw(grass, backGrass.getX(), backGrass.getY(), backGrass.getWidth(), backGrass.getHeight());
    }

    private void drawLogos() {
        // Draw the first logo
        if (bLogo1.isVisible() && logo.isAlive()) {
            batcher.draw(bonusLogoPlanet1, bLogo1.getX(), bLogo1.getY(), bLogo1.getWidth(), bLogo1.getHeight());
        }

        // Draw the second logo
        if (bLogo2.isVisible() && logo.isAlive()) {
            batcher.draw(bonusLogoPlanet2, bLogo2.getX(), bLogo2.getY(), bLogo2.getWidth(), bLogo2.getHeight());
        }

    }

    public void drawBullet() {
        if (myWorld.isRunning()) {
            if (bullet.isVisible() && logo.isAlive()) {
                batcher.draw(bonusLogoRocket, bullet.getX(), bullet.getY(), bullet.getWidth(), bullet.getHeight());
            }
        } else {
            bullet.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
    private void drawEnemyObject() {
        if (myWorld.isRunning()) {
            if (enemyObject.isVisible() && logo.isAlive()) {
                batcher.draw(enemyLogo, enemyObject.getX(), enemyObject.getY(), enemyObject.getWidth(), enemyObject.getHeight());
            }
        } else {
            enemyObject.setVisible(false);
        }

    }

    private void drawLogoCentered(float runTime) {
        batcher.draw(logoAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime), 59, logo.getY() - 15, logo.getWidth() / 2.0f,
                logo.getHeight() / 2.0f, logo.getWidth(), logo.getHeight(), 1, 1, logo.getRotation());
    }

    private void drawLogo(float runTime) {

        if (logo.shouldntFlap()) {
            batcher.draw(logoMid, logo.getX(), logo.getY(), logo.getWidth() / 2.0f, logo.getHeight() / 2.0f,
                    logo.getWidth(), logo.getHeight(), 1, 1, logo.getRotation());

        } else {
            batcher.draw(logoAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime), logo.getX(), logo.getY(), logo.getWidth() / 2.0f,
                    logo.getHeight() / 2.0f, logo.getWidth(), logo.getHeight(), 1, 1, logo.getRotation());
        }

    }

    private void drawMenuUI() {
        batcher.draw(mmGameLogo, 136 / 2 - 56, midPointY - 50, mmGameLogo.getRegionWidth() / 1.2f,
                mmGameLogo.getRegionHeight() / 1.2f);

        for (SimpleButton button : menuButtons) {
            button.draw(batcher);
        }

    }

    private void drawScoreboard() {
        batcher.draw(scoreboard, 22, midPointY - 30, 97, 37);

        batcher.draw(noStar, 25, midPointY - 15, 10, 10);
        batcher.draw(noStar, 37, midPointY - 15, 10, 10);
        batcher.draw(noStar, 49, midPointY - 15, 10, 10);
        batcher.draw(noStar, 61, midPointY - 15, 10, 10);
        batcher.draw(noStar, 73, midPointY - 15, 10, 10);

        if (myWorld.getScore() > 5) {
            batcher.draw(star, 73, midPointY - 15, 10, 10);
        }

        if (myWorld.getScore() > 17) {
            batcher.draw(star, 61, midPointY - 15, 10, 10);
        }

        if (myWorld.getScore() > 50) {
            batcher.draw(star, 49, midPointY - 15, 10, 10);
        }

        if (myWorld.getScore() > 80) {
            batcher.draw(star, 37, midPointY - 15, 10, 10);
        }

        if (myWorld.getScore() > 120) {
            batcher.draw(star, 25, midPointY - 15, 10, 10);
        }

        int length = ("" + myWorld.getScore()).length();

        AssetLoader.whiteFont.draw(batcher, "" + myWorld.getScore(), 104 - (2 * length), midPointY - 20);

        int length2 = ("" + AssetLoader.getHighScore()).length();
        AssetLoader.whiteFont.draw(batcher, "" + AssetLoader.getHighScore(), 104 - (2.5f * length2), midPointY - 3);

    }

    private void drawRetry() {
        batcher.draw(retry, 36, midPointY + 10, 66, 14);
    }

    private void drawReady() {
        batcher.draw(ready, 36, midPointY - 50, 68, 14);
    }

    private void drawGameOver() {
        batcher.draw(gameOver, 24, midPointY - 50, 92, 14);
    }

    private void drawScore() {
        int length = ("" + myWorld.getScore()).length();
        AssetLoader.shadow.draw(batcher, "" + myWorld.getScore(), 68 - (3 * length), midPointY - 82);
        AssetLoader.font.draw(batcher, "" + myWorld.getScore(), 68 - (3 * length), midPointY - 83);
    }

    private void drawHighScore() {
        batcher.draw(highScore, 22, midPointY - 50, 96, 14);
    }

    public void render(float delta, float runTime) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);

        // Draw Background color 108, 180, 226, 0.5f
        shapeRenderer.setColor(10 / 255.0f, 16 / 255.0f, 12 / 255.0f, 1);
        shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, 136, midPointY + 66);

        // Draw Grass
        shapeRenderer.setColor(111 / 255.0f, 186 / 255.0f, 45 / 255.0f, 1);
        shapeRenderer.rect(0, midPointY + 66, 136, 11);

        // Draw Dirt
        shapeRenderer.setColor(147 / 255.0f, 80 / 255.0f, 27 / 255.0f, 1);
        shapeRenderer.rect(0, midPointY + 77, 136, 52);

        shapeRenderer.end();

        batcher.begin();
        batcher.disableBlending();

        batcher.draw(bg, 0, midPointY + 23, 136, 43);


        drawEnemyObject();
        batcher.enableBlending();

        if (myWorld.isRunning()) {

            drawLogo(runTime);
            drawScore();
        } else if (myWorld.isReady()) {
            drawLogo(runTime);
            drawReady();
        } else if (myWorld.isMenu()) {
            drawLogoCentered(runTime);
            drawMenuUI();
        } else if (myWorld.isGameOver()) {
            drawScoreboard();
            drawLogo(runTime);
            drawGameOver();
            drawRetry();
        } else if (myWorld.isHighScore()) {
            drawScoreboard();
            drawLogo(runTime);
            drawHighScore();
            drawRetry();
        }

        drawGrass();
        batcher.end();
        batcher.begin();
        drawLogos();
        drawBullet();

        batcher.end();

        drawTransition(delta);

    }



    public void prepareTransition(int r, int g, int b, float duration) {
        transitionColor.set(r / 255.0f, g / 255.0f, b / 255.0f, 1);
        alpha.setValue(1);
        Tween.registerAccessor(Value.class, new ValueAccessor());
        manager = new TweenManager();
        Tween.to(alpha, -1, duration).target(0).ease(TweenEquations.easeOutQuad).start(manager);
    }

    private void drawTransition(float delta) {
        if (alpha.getValue() > 0) {
            manager.update(delta);
            Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
            Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
            shapeRenderer.setColor(transitionColor.r, transitionColor.g, transitionColor.b, alpha.getValue());
            shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, 136, 300);
            shapeRenderer.end();
            Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);

        }
    }
}
```

And this is my class where I actually creating them:

```
package com.vratsasoftware.gameobjects;

import com.vratsasoftware.gameworld.GameWorld;
import com.vratsasoftware.zbhelpers.Sound;

public class ScrollHandler {

    private Grass frontGrass, backGrass;
    private Pipe pipe1, pipe2;
    private BonusLogo bonusLogo1, bonusLogo2, bullet;
    private EnemyLogo enemyObject;
    private GameWorld gameWorld;

    public static final int SCROLL_SPEED = -59;
    public static final int PIPE_GAP = 143;
    public ScrollHandler(GameWorld gameWorld, float yPos) {
        this.gameWorld = gameWorld;

        frontGrass = new Grass(0, yPos, 143, 11, SCROLL_SPEED);
        backGrass = new Grass(frontGrass.getTailX(), yPos, 143, 11, SCROLL_SPEED);

        pipe1 = new Pipe(210, 0, 22, 60, SCROLL_SPEED, yPos);
        bonusLogo1 = new BonusLogo(pipe1.getTailX() + PIPE_GAP / 2, 50, 17, 12, SCROLL_SPEED);

        pipe2 = new Pipe(pipe1.getTailX() + PIPE_GAP, 0, 22, 60, SCROLL_SPEED, yPos);
        bonusLogo2 = new BonusLogo(pipe2.getTailX() + PIPE_GAP / 2, 50, 17, 12, SCROLL_SPEED);

        bullet = new BonusLogo(gameWorld.getLogo().getX(), gameWorld.getLogo().getY(),
                (int) gameWorld.getLogo().getWidth(), (int) gameWorld.getLogo().getHeight(), -SCROLL_SPEED);

        setEnemyObject(new EnemyLogo(140, 15, 40, 40, SCROLL_SPEED));
    }



    public void updateReady(float delta) {
        frontGrass.update(delta);
        backGrass.update(delta);
        // Same with grass
        if (frontGrass.isScrolledLeft()) {
            frontGrass.reset(backGrass.getTailX());
        } else if (backGrass.isScrolledLeft()) {
            backGrass.reset(frontGrass.getTailX());
        }

    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        // Update our objects
        frontGrass.update(delta);
        backGrass.update(delta);
        pipe1.update(delta);
        bonusLogo1.update(delta);
        pipe2.update(delta);
        bonusLogo2.update(delta);
        bullet.update(delta);
        enemyObject.update(delta);
        // Check if any of the pipes are scrolled left, and reset accordingly
        // the bonusLogo
        if (pipe1.isScrolledLeft()) {
            pipe1.reset(pipe2.getTailX() + PIPE_GAP);
            bonusLogo2.reset(pipe2.getTailX() + PIPE_GAP / 2);
        } else if (pipe2.isScrolledLeft()) {
            pipe2.reset(pipe1.getTailX() + PIPE_GAP);
            bonusLogo1.reset(pipe1.getTailX() + PIPE_GAP / 2);
        }
        // Same with grass
        if (frontGrass.isScrolledLeft()) {
            frontGrass.reset(backGrass.getTailX());
        } else if (backGrass.isScrolledLeft()) {
            backGrass.reset(frontGrass.getTailX());
        }

        if (enemyObject.isScrolledLeft()) {
            enemyObject.reset(enemyObject.getTailX() + PIPE_GAP);

        } else if (enemyObject.isScrolledLeft()) {
            enemyObject.reset(enemyObject.getTailX() + PIPE_GAP);

        }



    }

    public void stop() {
        frontGrass.stop();
        backGrass.stop();
        pipe1.stop();
        pipe2.stop();
        bonusLogo1.stop();
        bonusLogo2.stop();
        bullet.stop();
        enemyObject.stop();
    }



    public void onRestart() {
        frontGrass.onRestart(0, SCROLL_SPEED);
        backGrass.onRestart(frontGrass.getTailX(), SCROLL_SPEED);
        pipe1.onRestart(210, SCROLL_SPEED);
        bonusLogo1.onRestart(pipe1.getTailX() + PIPE_GAP / 2, SCROLL_SPEED);
        pipe2.onRestart(pipe1.getTailX() + PIPE_GAP, SCROLL_SPEED);
        bonusLogo2.onRestart(pipe2.getTailX() + PIPE_GAP / 2, SCROLL_SPEED);
        bullet.onRestart(gameWorld.getLogo().getX(), -SCROLL_SPEED);
        enemyObject.onRestart(210, SCROLL_SPEED);
    }



    private void addScore(int increment) {
        gameWorld.addScore(increment);
    }

    public boolean scored(Logo bird) {
        if (bonusLogo1.collides(bird)) {
            if (!bonusLogo1.isScored()) {
                bonusLogo1.setScored(true);
                Sound.playCoin();
                addScore(1);
                bonusLogo1.setVisible(false);

                return true;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else if (bonusLogo2.collides(bird)) {
            if (!bonusLogo2.isScored()) {
                bonusLogo2.setScored(true);
                Sound.playCoin();
                addScore(1);
                bonusLogo2.setVisible(false);

                return true;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else if (enemyObject.collides(bullet)) {
            if (!enemyObject.isScored() && enemyObject.isVisible() && bullet.isVisible()) {
                enemyObject.setScored(true);
                Sound.playHit();
                enemyObject.setVisible(false);
                bullet.setVisible(false);

                return true;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Grass getFrontGrass() {
        return frontGrass;
    }

    public Grass getBackGrass() {
        return backGrass;
    }

    public Pipe getPipe1() {
        return pipe1;
    }

    public Pipe getPipe2() {
        return pipe2;
    }

    public BonusLogo getBonusLogo1() {
        return bonusLogo1;
    }

    public BonusLogo getBonusLogo2() {
        return bonusLogo2;
    }

    public BonusLogo getBullet() {
        return bullet;
    }



    public EnemyLogo getEnemyObject() {
        return enemyObject;
    }



    public void setEnemyObject(EnemyLogo enemyLogo) {
        this.enemyObject = enemyLogo;
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. It's not eclipse doing this, that's just the IDE. 2. Consider switching to Android Studio, it's the recommended IDE. 3. No one can help you without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: You sure the white is not in the original image ?

Comment: Yes I am sure its png file and there is no background color on it it's empty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `drawEnemyObject();` before you enable blending again, which means the transparent background on your enemy object is showing up as white. Try placing the `drawEnemyObject();` after you re-enable blending in the batch.

Like so:

```
batcher.enableBlending()
drawEnemyObject();
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!